# Need different versions of the same dependency in maven child projects

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I would like to test in Eclipse the integration of Java rest server and a rest client.
Both the hello-client and the hello-server projects depend on the same hello-model jar file (that contains POJOs).

The catch is that I would like to check out different versions of either the client or the server, be able to edit the code in eclipse and be able to debug the test - even if they depend on different versions of hello-model.

I tried to use the Maven shade plugin to rename the model package in the server:

hellopojo.model -> hellopojo.server.model

but it does not affect Eclipse (wrong Maven stage I suppose).

```xml
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <relocations>
            <relocation>
              <pattern>hellopojo.model</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>hellopojo.server.model</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
          </relocations>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the unit test code:

```
@Parameters({"port"})
@BeforeClass
public static void startWebapp(
@Optional("8081") int port) throws Exception {

    restUri = "http://localhost:"+port+"/rest";
    client = new HelloClient(new URI(restUri));

    server = new Server(port);
    server.setHandler(createWebAppContext());
    server.start();
}


private static ServletContextHandler createWebAppContext() {
    ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    handler.setContextPath("/");
    ServletHolder servlet = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer());
    servlet.setInitParameter(
        "com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", 
        HelloResource.class.getPackage().getName());
    servlet.setInitParameter(
        "com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature" ,
        "true");
    handler.addServlet(servlet, "/rest/*");
    return handler;
}

@AfterClass
public static void stopWebapp() throws Exception {
    server.stop();
}
```

Related question on stackoverflow:
[Best Git strategy for testing different client and server versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314017/best-git-strategy-for-testing-different-client-and-server-versions)

Complete Code:
https://github.com/itaifrenkel/hellopojo/blob/master/hellopojo-test/src/test/java/hellopojo/test/HelloTest.java

Comment: Do you have both the server and the client in the same project-structure? What about splitting them in two distinct projects with distinct pom-files?

Comment: I have two Pom files (client and server), that refer to a third common Pom file (model). So I end up with three eclipse projects. The problem is that each of the two projects may reference a different version of the common (model) Pom project.

Comment: I thought you wanted to allow different versions of 'common'... I'm not very into Maven anymore, but AFAIK you can create a *parent* project-pom, define your dependencies there (the one to common), and derive from that pom for client and server.

Comment: I could, but then both subprojects would have to use the same version of dependent module. This is not what I require. I need the ability for the client and the server use different versions of module.

Comment: You have a server-pom with a dependency to common and a client-pom with a dependency to common. So you can change the version of the dependencies independently (plus `eclipse:eclipse` in client and server, and it updates the common-lib in eclipse)...

Answer (score 3):

We use dependencyManagement concept of Maven projects to handle this.

Step 1 - Declare dependencyManagement in the parent pom of the client and server project.

Step 2 - In the dependency sections of the client and server project override the version information.

This might help you get through the test scope classpath. I am not sure what will it do to the compile scope classpath.

Comment: Did you try using dependencyManagement section? Is your hello-model within the same project hierarchy?